# NameError global name PortScanner is not defined, but it's defined already

Tags: python-2.7

Im having this issue with my following code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RecursoveScan.py", line 28, in <module>
    class PortScanner(threading.Thread):
  File "RecursoveScan.py", line 95, in PortScanner
    main()
  File "RecursoveScan.py", line 83, in main
    thread = PortScanner()
NameError: global name 'PortScanner' is not definedTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "RecursoveScan.py", line 28, in <module>
    class PortScanner(threading.Thread):
  File "RecursoveScan.py", line 95, in PortScanner
    main()
  File "RecursoveScan.py", line 83, in main
    thread = PortScanner()
NameError: global name 'PortScanner' is not defined
```

But at line 26, i have this defined. Please help.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import time
import argparse
import socket
import threading
import thread

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Single Host Service scan')      
parser,add_argument('-host',action='store',dest='host',required=True,help='Set Remote Host IP')
parser.add_argument('-portrange',action='store',dest='portrange',required=True,help='Set Portscan Range')
parser.add_argument('-threads',action='store',dest='thread',type=int,required=True,help='Set Number of Threads (10-100)')
args = parser.parse_args()

class PortScanner(threading.Thread):
    openportcount = 0


    def __init__(self, hostname, portrange):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.hostname = args.host
        self.portrange = args.portrange

    def run(self):
        while True:
            for port in range(self.portrange[0],self.portrange[1]):
                sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                print status
                if status == 0:
                    print "Port %d      |OPEN|"%port
                    PortScanner.openportcount+=1
                    sock.close()
                else:
                    print "Port %d      |CLOSED|"%port
                    PortScanner.closedportcount+=1
                    socket.close()


    def main():
        print("[*] Port Scanner Starting..\n")
        portrange = list((args.portrange.split("-")))


        lport = int(portrange[0])
        uport = int(portrange[1])

        if lport>uport:
            tempport = uport
            uport = lport
            lport = tempport

        if uport > 65535:
            uport = 65535
            print"[!] Port ranges must be 0-65535\n[!] Port Range Set To %d - 65535\n"%lport
        elif lport < 0:
            lport = 0
        print"[!] Port ranges must be 0-65535\n[!] Port range set to 0 - %d\n"%uport

        no_of_threads = args.thread

        r = (uport -lport)/no_of_threads
        print"\n[+] %d Threads Starting.\n"%no_of_threads

        threads = []
        for i in range(10,no_of_threads):
            uport = lport +r+ 1
            if uport>65535:
                uport=65535
            ports = [lport, uport]
            thread = PortScanner()
            lport = uport+1
            thread.start()
            threads.append(thread)

        for t in threads:
            t.join()

        print("\n %d Open Ports Found!"%PortScanner.openportcount)
        print("\n %d Closed Ports Detected!"%PortScanner.closedportcount)
        print("\nDONE..")

    main()
```

I've tried over and over, But still cannot figure out why it's giving me this error. I'm pretty new to python, and not the best at it. Appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: I don't see how this line possibly executes without error: `parser,add_argument('-host',action='store',dest='host',required=True,help='Set Remote Host IP')` (note the `,` instead of the `.`)

Comment: That's a typo, i had to space lines out and re add them by accident.

Comment: @AnthonySottile: Please don't edit indentation in Python questions, especially when it looks like the bug may be due to indentation errors. Looking at the traceback, this definitely looks like an indentation error. The definition and call of `main` appear to be inside the definition of `PortScanner`.

Comment: Okay, Thanks! As i said man, i've been into python for about 2 months now. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @user2357112 I only fixed the indentation due to "PS, All the code below class PortScanner(threading.Thread): is indented, but not shown on the code sample. Sorry about that!"